# spark(scala) three separated rdd[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] to a single rdd[Vector]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, vector, apache-spark-mllib

i have three separated rdd[mllib....vectors] and i need to combine them as a one rdd[mllib vector].

```
val vvv = my_ds.map(x=>(scaler.transform(Vectors.dense(x(0))),Vectors.dense((x(1)/bv_max_2).toArray),Vectors.dense((x(2)/bv_max_1).toArray)))
```

more info:
scaler => StandardScaler
bv_max_... is nothing but the DenseVector from breeze lib in case for normalizing (x/max(x))

now i need to make them all as one 
i get ([1.],[2.],[3.]) and [[1.],[2.],[3.]]
but i need [1.,2.,3.] as one vector

Comment: Can you share an example dataset please? As of now your code isn't reproducible.

Comment: the above code generates this :  
([-1.0879352081573068],[0.1282051282051282],[1.0])
([-0.33536545781646926],[0.1282051282051282],[1.0])............ and the dataset part ===> val my_ds = raw_ds.map(x=>Vectors.dense(x.days,x.freq,x.food)) and this is the sample of raw_data===> 23,5,2 ......however i need to combine the above vvv to be maped as a single vector as ([-0.33536545781646926],[0.1282051282051282],[1.0]) ===to===>[-0.33536545781646926,0.1282051282051282,1.0] and so i can pass it to KMeans ... i hope this helps ...thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

finally i found ... i dont know if this is the best.

i had 3d data set and i needed to perform x/max(x) normalization on two  dimensions  and apply standardScaler to another dimension.
my problem was that in the end i had 3 separated Vectors like: eg
[ [1.0],[4,0],[5.0] ]
[ [2.0], [5.0], [6.0]]................but i needed [1.0,4.0,5.0] which can be passed to KMeans.
i changed the above code as :

```
val vvv = dsx.map(x=>scaler.transform(Vectors.dense(x.days_d)).toArray ++ (x.freq_d/bv_max_freq).toArray ++ (x.food_d/bv_max_food).toArray).map(x=>Vectors.dense(x(0),x(1),x(2)))
```